# What are performant, scalable ways to resolve links from http://bit.ly

Tags: java, performance, scala, scalability

Given a series of URLS from a stream where millions could be bit.ly, google or tinyurl shortened links, what is the most scalable way to resolve those to get their final url?

A Multi-threaded crawler doing HEAD requests on each short link while caching ones you've already resolved? Are there services that already provide this?

Also factor in not getting blocked from the url shortening service.
Assume the scale is 20 million shortened urls per day.

Comment: bit.ly for instance has an API available that could help you out here, but I'm not sure they'd be entirely happy serving 20 million requests from you per day.

Comment: Probably you shall use async IO or at least selectors for this, in other case you will end up with bottleneck in CPU/Threading.

Answer (score 6):

Google [provides an API](http://code.google.com/apis/urlshortener/).  So does [bit.ly](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) (and bit.ly asks to be notified of heavy use, and specify what they mean by light usage).  I am not aware of an appropriate API for tinyurl (for decoding), but there may be one.

Then you have to fetch on the order of 230 URLs per second to keep up with your desired rates.  I would measure typical latencies for each service and create one master actor and as many worker actors as you needed so the actors could block on lookup.  (I'd use Akka for this, not default Scala actors, and make sure each worker actor gets its own thread!)

You also should cache the answers locally; it's much faster to look up a known answer than it is to ask these services for one.  (The master actor should take care of that.)

After that, if you still can't keep up because of, for example, throttling by the sites, you had better either talk to the sites or you'll have to do things that are rather questionable (rent a bunch of inexpensive servers at different sites and farm out the requests to them).

Comment: Cool that bit.ly has API (+1). But he has to support other services too. And you need 1000 threads to get 230 URLs per second.

Comment: @AlexR - 4s per lookup?  That's a bit slow.  None of the sites take that long to do a redirect.  Anyway, even if he does need 1000 threads, that isn't really a problem; the JVM can support that many without much effort.  It would be more elegant (but probably harder to code) to use NIO, though.

Answer (score 2):

Using HEAD method is an interesting idea by I am afraid it can fail because I am not sure the services you mentioned support HEAD at all. If for example the service is implemented as a java servlet it can implement doGet() only. In this case doHead() is unsupported.

I'd suggest you to try to use GET but do not read the whole response. Read HTTP status line only.

As far as you have very serious requirements for performance you cannot these requests synchronously, i.e. you cannot use HttpUrlConnection. You should use NIO package directly. In this case you will be able to send requests to all millions of destinations using only one thread and get responses very quickly.